# Prims Algorithm for Minimum Spanning Tree Analysis

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

Algorithm:
[image]

Graph:
[image]

(Note: Missing edge weight, (T, Y, 8))

Before the first iteration:

The min priority Queue(min key at start)

Q = [(S, 0), (T, ∞), (X, ∞), (Y, ∞), (Z, ∞)]

Iteration 1:

U = S

Q = [(T, 6), (Y, 7), (X, ∞), (Z, ∞)]

Updates Keys of T and Y

Iteration 2:

U = T

Q = [(Z, -4), (X, 5), (Y, 7)]

Updates Keys of X, Y, Z

Iteration 3:

U = Z

Q = [(X, 5), (Y, 7)]

No updates

Iteration 4:

U = X

Q = [(Y, 7)]

No updates

Iteration 5:

U = Y

Q = []

No updates

Queue empty, loop terminates

We have the following edges in our minimum spanning tree:

(S, T, 6), (T, Z, 5), (T, Z, -4), (S, Y, 7)

Cost = 6 + 5 - 4 + 7 = 14

This is obviously not a MST because we have other trees with lesser cost,

(S, Y, 7), (Y, X, -3), (X, T -2), (T, Z, -4)

Cost = 7 - 3 - 2 - 4 = -2

Please help me identify where I have gone wrong.

For reference:
(Please ignore the red edges)

Iteration 1:
[image]

Iteration 2:
[image]

Iteration 3:
[image]

Iteration 4:
[image]

Iteration 5:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In computer science, Prim's algorithm is a greedy algorithm that finds a minimum 
spanning tree for a **weighted undirected graph**.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree